# Intersection of one-sheeted hyperboloid and plane is a geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the one-sheeted hyperboloid:
$$ S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2-z^2=1 \}  .$$
Prove that the intersection of S with a plane of the type
$$ ax+by=0 \text{ , with } (a,b) \neq (0,0)$$
is a geodesic.

---

What conditions would that intersection need to satisfy for us to be able to prove that it's indeed a geodesic? I checked the DoCarmo book about differential geometry, but am still not sure how to proceed.

Comment: It would have to satisfy the definition of a geodesic. Presumably you’ve learned that?

Comment: @Deane , thanks for the reply. What I understand is that a geodesic acts locally as a distance minimizer in a given Riemannian manifold.

Comment: OK. That's a start. Have you learned any more than that about geodesics? Perhaps, before trying to attack this problem, you should first learn about geodesics in a surface in 3-space. It's a little early to be thinking about Riemannian manifolds. The relevant term you want to understand is "geodesic curvature".